# Screen Turns Black after tilted past about 70°

Tags: mac, mojave, screen

2 or 3 weeks ago, when I tilted my screen past 90° it just went black. I was confused, so I closed my laptop and it worked. I tried again, the same thing. Eventually, I couldn't even turn it past 70° without it switching off. Any ideas why this is, if it's just a temporary issue, or if I'll need to get it repaired? Thanks. (My Model is a MacBook Pro 13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports. macOS Mojave 10.14.)

Comment: This is a known defect with the LVDS cable.  You need to take it in for service.

Comment: Thanks, I got it repaired a few months ago. Thank you for the quick reply!